# Quarkus Cache API Response from Pub Sub

Tags: caching, quarkus, publish-subscribe

I want to put some data in the cache in quarkus for at least for 30 min, the data which is subscribe from the pubsub. what method i need to apply and how do i know that data is really store for that particular time which i mention?

I have try to implement this by reading the documentation but that doesn't help.

Comment: The configuration for how long to retain the values can be found in https://quarkus.io/guides/cache#caffeine-configuration-properties. As for what method to use, well, you should not have to put things in the cache explicitly, it's all declarative: https://quarkus.io/guides/cache#annotations-api

Comment: Please demonstrate any effort to find a solution yourself. Quarkus has great documentation on the caching.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.